# AWS EC2 get the AMI size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, snapshot, amazon-ami

I am Using ec2 and creating a custom AMI using a snapshot for my machine. I Can't find how to get it's actual size on disk to calculate the cost it will charge me to store it.

How can I get the actual compressed size or estimated cost for storing an AMI (snapshot of a machine)

Answer (score 5):

AMI sizes are not easy to calculate. This is because they are based on Amazon EBS snapshots, and EBS snapshots are incremental in nature.

For example:

- Let's say you launch an instance from an Amazon Linux AMI
- You then login and create a file on the disk
- You then create a new AMI

Any blocks that have been added or changed (eg for the new file on the disk) will be included in your AMI (or, more accurately, in the snapshot that stores the AMI data). However, all the blocks that were *not* modified from the original AMI are not stored in *your* AMI. Instead, the AMI will contain a reference to the blocks in the original AMI. This is due to the *incremental* nature of snapshots.

So, the reality is that most of an AMI (most of a snapshot) actually contains pointers to existing data and it therefore is *not* charged to you. You will only pay for storage that does not already exist.

That's why you can't really get the storage size of an AMI.

The only way to know the storage size for sure would be to create a totally new AMI that is not based on an existing AMI, since you would then be charged for the total size. (I wouldn't recommend doing so.)

Comment: So i am not able to predict the cost of storage in any way?

Comment: Not that I am aware. The up-side is that the storage is probably much less than you expect, since blocks from the original AMI will not be charged and each block is only charged once even if it is in multiple snapshots/AMIs.

Comment: Thanks. weird, I would expect amazon to be able to tell me how much i'm gonna be charged (even on total size of all my snapshots together) otherwise, how can they calculate how much to actually charge me?

Comment: Yes, the amounts is shown on the AWS bill but the breakdown is not provided per-AMI.

Comment: I am looking for a way to understand how much bill i'm gonna get before i am actually getting it. Ideas?